# Get only 1 occurrence for the duplicate records

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
select DISTINCT a.Schooldistricttown, a.Schooldistrictnum 
from [Legacy].[dbo].[MyTables] as a
```

It returns :

[image]

Can you tell me how to get only one occurrence of `a.Schooldistricttown`?
I have tried with `DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY`. But it's not working.

**Note :** I need to show both columns also.

Comment: You need all values or only min or max of them? Or all comma separated?

Comment: @Sampath and you dont care whether there will be inserted 13 or 30?

Comment: @IvanStarostin Yes,No problem there.

Comment: @gofr1 Only one value of `a.Schooldistrictnum` column.No problem about which value.

Comment: If you don't care which value then why select any value at all? Just select `Schooldistricttown`

Comment: Possible answers are already given by @sagi. Anyway it's a strange scenario.

Comment: @juergend B'cos I'm going to insert it into a `not null` column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options, if it doesn't matter which value you get in `Schooldistrictnum` then group by with `MAX()/MIN()` will solve this:

```
SELECT a.Schooldistricttown,MAX(a.Schooldistrictnum)
from [Legacy].[dbo].[MyTables] a
GROUP BY a.Schooldistricttown
```

If you do care, use `ROW_NUMBER()` :

```
SELECT s.Schooldistricttown,s.Schooldistrictnum
FROM (
    SELECT a.Schooldistricttown,a.Schooldistrictnum,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY a.Schooldistricttown ORDER BY a.<ORDER_COLUMN>) as rnk
    from [Legacy].[dbo].[MyTables]  a) s
WHERE s.rnk = 1
```

You need to replace `<ORDER_COLUMN>` with the actual column that you decide which value you want by it

Comment: `GROUP BY` is more than enough for me.Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want all `Schooldistrictnum`, use this

```
  SELECT DISTINCT 
    a.Schooldistricttown,
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT 
            ina.Schooldistrictnum + ', ' AS [text()]
        FROM 
            [Legacy].[dbo].[MyTables] as ina
        WHERE
            ina.Schooldistricttown =  a.Schooldistricttown
        FOR XML PATH ('')
     ) AS Schooldistrictnum 
   FROM [Legacy].[dbo].[MyTables] as a
```